# Multivariate distribution: calculate P(Y > b/2)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, multivariate-distribution

The joint probability function looks like this: 
[image: Joint probability function]
The first step for calculating $P(Y > 2/b)$ is calculating $f_Y(y)$.
Which I did like this:
[image: f_Y(y)]

The problem here is that my x is still in my indicator, and I don't know how to get it out.

A tip I got is to work with the conditional probability $f_{Y|X=z}(y)$ instead. Which if I calculated it correctly should be equal to 1/b. I can't seem to figure out what the relation is between the $f_{Y|X=z}(y)$ and $f_Y(y)$, and how I could calculate $P(Y > 2/b)$ with them. Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you are integrating over $x$ to find $f_Y()$, you are ignoring the restriction on $x$ from $-\frac{bx}{2a}-\frac{b}{2}<y<-\frac{bx}{2a}+\frac{b}{2}$. And indeed you can work with the conditional distribution $Y\mid X$ to find the probability since it is clear that the joint density factors as $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\underbrace{\frac{1}{b}\mathbb I \left(-\frac{bx}{2a}-\frac{b}{2}<y<-\frac{bx}{2a}+\frac{b}{2}\right)}_{f_{Y\mid X}(y)}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{1}{2a}\mathbb I(-a<x<a)}_{f_X(x)}$$

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks for the answer!  I understand that, but to calculate $P(Y > 2/b)$ you need to calculate  $\int_{b/2}^{-b/2ax+b/2}f_Y(y)$. How can you get this from the conditional distribution?

Comment: By total probability theorem, $$P\left(Y>\frac{2}{b}\right)=\int P\left(Y>\frac{2}{b}\,\bigg|\ X=x\right)f_X(x)\,dx$$ It's the same thing as finding the marginal of $Y$ first and then integrating.

Comment: Thank you very much @StubbornAtom! So this should be right?
$$(P > 2/b) = \int_{a}^{-a} ( \int_{b/2}^{-bx/2a-b/2} 1/b  dy) 1/2a dx $$

Comment: You have to carefully setup the bounds of the integrals. That's the main job here.

Comment: @StubbornAtom so the bounds I've used in the comment above aren't right? The bounds of the outer integral correspond with the restrictions on x. And the lower bound of the outer integral is the value that Y should be greater than and the upper bound of the outer integral corresponds with the restriction on y.

Comment: Also the upper bound in the inner integral should be $-bx/2a + b/2$. That was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The polygon is the support of the distribution and the dashed horizontal line corresponds to $Y=b/2$. Hence the probability of interest is proportional to the yellow part.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: So the lower bound of my outer integral shouldn't be -a, but the X value on the point that Y becomes lower than b/2? Which is 0 in this case?

Comment: $-b/2\le y+b/2 x\le b/2$ is a constraint on both $(x,y)$.

Comment: Combining your answer and that one of StubbornAtom I've come to this formula:
$$ P(Y > b/2) = \int_{0}^{a} (\int_{b/2}^{-b/2ax+b/2} (1/b) dy ) (1/2a) dx  $$
But you are saying this isn't right?
When calculating this I get 1/8. Which seems to correspond with the yellow area.

Comment: My bad, it should be [-a, 0], right? Thanks!